# "stereoscope" package installation in Python

Tags: python, numpy, installation, pip, numba

I have installed the package "stereoscope" successfully a few days ago and have been using it to do analysis. However, when I am trying to use it today I got the error that the command "stereoscope" is not found. I suspect that this error usually comes up when the package is not installed. It is weird I know. Therefore, I tried to install it again. However, I found the problem "numpy 1.21.1 is installed but numpy<1.21,>=1.17 is required by {'numba'}". What I understand from this error is that I need to install the NumPy version less than 1.21.1 or greater than or equal to 1.17. So, I tried to install the required version such as NumPy 1.20.3. The issue remains the same. I do not know why it is still saying my numpy version is 1.21.1 even after I uninstalled this version. Please help me with how to resolve this issue?

This is the link where I follow to do the installation [stereoscope installation](https://github.com/almaan/stereoscope/blob/master/README.md)

I tried to update the numba and use the command "pip list" to get numba version is 0.53.1 and the numpy version is 1.21.1. But still do not resolve the error. I have uninstalled the numpy version 1.21.1 and change it to numpy version 1.20.3 but the error remains.

Comment: if you do ```pip list```, what is the version of numpy mentioned there? Also, you mean that you cannot import the package ```stereotype```?

Comment: @flyinthelotion I only got this Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        21.2.3
setuptools 57.0.0
six        1.16.0
wheel      0.36.2.     I cannot install the package "stereoscope"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by uninstalled all version of numpy that present on my system. I then create a new virtual environment. I start install the package stereoscope including all required packages on this virtual environment. This way there will be no crush between these installation and my computer system.